# Python how to replace a column's values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

If there is a column called `date` in a `pandas.DataFrame`, For which the values are:

```
'2018-02-01', 
'2018-02-02',
 ...
```

How do I change all the values to integers? For example:

```
'20180201', 
'20180202',
 ...
```

Comment: `.replace` the dashes with empty strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.str.replace()` like:

#### Code:

```
df['newdate'] = df['date'].str.replace('-', '')
```

or if not using a regex, faster as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

```
df['newdate'] = [x.replace('-', '') for x in df['date']]
```

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['2018-02-01', '2018-02-02'], columns=['date'])
print(df)

df['newdate'] = df['date'].str.replace('-', '')
print(df)

df['newdate2'] = [x.replace('-', '') for x in df['date']]
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
         date
0  2018-02-01
1  2018-02-02

         date   newdate
0  2018-02-01  20180201
1  2018-02-02  20180202

         date   newdate  newdate2
0  2018-02-01  20180201  20180201
1  2018-02-02  20180202  20180202
```